# How to create a RTE box for 1 field of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

For a wordpress site we're developing, we import data from somewhere else and add them as custom post types to the database. For these fields the customer wants to be able to manually edit one of those field with an RTE interface. How do I do that. The site is using Custom Post Type UI to show the posts in the backend, but they're all extra fields. I want one of these fields to be an textarea with an RTE, how do I do this?

These are the fields as shown in Wordpress. vac_description should be an rte

[image]